# Update Duplicate Records

Tags: sql, hana

I have a column store table, TABLE_HANA with the below data in HANA DB:

```
T_ID1   T_ID2   T_DESC  T_RN
1        1      AAA       ?
1        1      BBB       ?
1        2      CCC       ?
1        3      DDD       ?
1        3      EEE       ?
```

I need to group them by T_ID1 and T_ID2 and update the T_RN column of that group with a sequential value as shown below:

```
T_ID1   T_ID2   T_DESC  T_RN
1        1       AAA    1
1        1       BBB    2
1        2       CCC    1
1        3       DDD    1
1        3       EEE    2
```

Since the table is very huge(millions of records), I am looking for a solution with good performance. Please suggest.

TIA

Comment: If `Row_Number` window function is supported in `HANA` then you can use it

Comment: Using Row_Number we can generate the select output as shown above, how can an update be done on the table.Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The first question is whether you really need to do the update.  The following query returns what you want:

```
select h.*,
       row_number() over (partition by t_id1, t_id2 order by t_desc) as t_rn
from table_hana h;
```

This may be sufficient.

The update will probably be expensive:

```
update table_hana h
    set t_rn = (select count(*)
                from table_hana h2
                where h2.t_id1 = h.t_id1 and h2.t_id2 = h.t_id2 and h2.desc <= h.desc
               );
```

An index on `table_hana(t_id1, t_id2, t_desc)` should help both these queries.

Comment: Can the update query be made independent of the T_DESC column. As they might have NULL values in some cases.

Comment: @MaveriK . . . What you really need is a unique identifier for reach row.  That would be better than `desc` anyway.